# "Bypass" Smartscreen with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, batch-file, uac

I am working on a macro for my office that does a variety of things. Notably it acesses the internet with SeleniumBasic. As not very user that access this macro has this program installed by default (as I am the one who began the experiment), I devised a way to also use a macro to download and install Selenium, chromedriver with proper version, and another browser in the case of chrome not working (Has happened bc of cache overflow when loading websites). All of this works lovely when created and ran on my device. Testing with other devices I managed to work out a significant number of bugs and the department decided to roll it out to everyone else thinging we had fixed most of everything. Unfortunately another unexpected bug occurred on a device when running today. I went to the computer to manually to install the program but also figure out what was causing the issue. I believe I found it but now I need help determining how to get around it.

As these are company computers, there are only certain programs allowed to be installed. Everything is denied by default but you can cancel the UAC and the program will install as normal. When I debugged what happened to this one device, Selenium installed properly, as it should but when attempting to launch chrome form the chrome driver, the program stopped responding and crashed. I suspected this was due to the chromedriver not actually getting changed to the proper version and found a compound problem.

Problem 1: For this device (not encountered on others that were tested) attempting to manually run the chrome driver prompted the UAC for SmartScreen. Company computer limited me and I was unable to disable it but i can click more info and "run anyway" and it will run. So i need some way to "bypass" when this prompt shows up
Problem 2: If this or another error occures when one of the batch files in running, the batch file is unable to complete and gets suspended and cannot exit. Is there a way that if an error happens within the batch for it to exit?

Here is the code segment that is getting hung up. The driver test gets hung up when the smartscreen prompts in the background it causes Selenium to bug out and crashes Excel.
On some devices the wait loop for testing if the file is deleted is failing causing crashes as well. Tho it should not be possible it keeps saying that file is already in location, even with the wait and delete statement before the new file gets pasted in.

```
If Dir("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Err.Raise 400, "Custom", ".NET Framework 3.5 not installed on this device. Macros will not run without it."
    End If
    Debug.Print "Chrome Test 2: Passed"
    
    'Add Selenium if not installed
    If Dir(Userpath & SeleniumPath & "Scripts", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        If Dir(Userpath & SeleniumPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
            'End Excel and force delete Selenium Folder
            RestartNow = MsgBox("There has been failed attempts to install Selenium Previously. All Excel processes will be closed to resolve this problem. Upon restart. Run macro again." & vbNewLine & "Close All Excel Instances now?", vbOKCancel, vbCritical)
            If RestartNow <> 1 Then
                MsgBox "Please Save work in other excel instances then re-run Macro."
                SeleniumTest = False
                Exit Function
            End If

            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            EXCELWindowID = GetCurrentProcessId
            'Create create deletion file
            
            Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumForceRemoval.bat") 'Close Excel and Force Delete Selenium Folder
            Outputstring = "taskkill /f /im excel.exe" _
                            & vbNewLine & "timeout 2" _
                            & vbNewLine & "rmdir /s /q " & Userpath & "\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic" _
                            & vbNewLine & "start excel " & Chr(34) & "https://elcompanies.sharepoint.com/sites/DistributionManagement/Shared Documents/General/LM Test/LastMile AutoUpdater New.xlsm" & Chr(34)
            objFile.Write (Outputstring)
            objFile.Close
            'Run File
            Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            installer = wsh.Run(Chr(34) & Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumForceRemoval.bat" & Chr(34), 0, True)
            
            'Excel Will close at this point and delete Selenium Folder
        End If
    
InstallOverride:

ufProgress.Caption = "Installing Selenium..."
If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
Resume
Err.Clear
End If
        SeleniumDownload = DownloadFileFromWeb(SeleniumURL, Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumBasic.exe")
        ChromeDriverDownload = DownloadFileFromWeb(chromeURL, Userpath & downloadPath & "chromedriver.zip")
        
        'Check if Downloaded Correctly
        If Not SeleniumDownload = 0 And ChromeDriverDownload = 0 Then
            MsgBox "1 or more downloads failed. Please check your internet connection"
            Debug.Print "If this error presists after checking internet connection, check to see if either of the download links are no longer in use."
            Debug.Print "It is also possible that the driver versions is no longer valid. Please check driver version"
            Debug.Print "Add new chrome driver version to chromedriverURLs if version is newer than newest driver"
            Err.Raise 513, "Custom", "Download File From Web Failed to get file"
        End If
        Debug.Print "Selenium Test 1: Passed"
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        'Create autoinstaller.bat file Selenium
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumAutoInstaller.bat")
        Outputstring = "start /wait " & Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumBasic.exe /verysilent" & vbNewLine & "EXIT"
        objFile.Write (Outputstring)
        objFile.Close
        Debug.Print "Selenium Test 2.1: Passed"
        'Install Selenium via .bat file
        Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        installer = wsh.Run(Chr(34) & Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumAutoInstaller.bat" & Chr(34), 0, True)
        Debug.Print "Selenium Test 2.2: Passed"
        'Delete default driver
    On Error Resume Next
        Kill (Userpath & SeleniumPath & "chromedriver.exe")
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
        'Copy the files & folders from the zip into a folder (Corrected Chrome Driver)
        If Not Dir(Userpath & downloadPath & "chromedriver.exe") = "" Then
            'Remove old file if attempted before
            Kill (Userpath & SeleniumPath & "chromedriver.exe")
        End If
        
        'Extract Zip file  at new Location
        Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        ShellApp.Namespace(Userpath & downloadPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(Userpath & downloadPath & "chromedriver.zip").Items
        Debug.Print "Selenium Test 3: Passed"
        
        'Wait till deleted
        While Not Dir(Userpath & SeleniumPath & "chromedriver.exe") = ""
            Sleep 200
        Wend
        
        'Paste proper driver
        FSO.CopyFile Userpath & downloadPath & "chromedriver.exe", Userpath & SeleniumPath
        Debug.Print "Selenium Test 4: Passed"
        
        'Clean Up
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill (Userpath & downloadPath & "chromedriver.exe")
        Kill (Userpath & downloadPath & "chromedriver.zip")
        Kill (Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumAutoInstaller.bat")
        Kill (Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumBasic.exe")
        Kill (Userpath & downloadPath & "SeleniumForceRemoval.bat")
        Set FSO = Nothing
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        Set ShellApp = Nothing
        Set wsh = Nothing
        Debug.Print "SeleniumBasic has been added to user " & currUser
    Else
        Debug.Print "Selenium Already Installed"
    End If
    
    'Test if chrome and launch properly
    ufProgress.Caption = "Testing Install"
    x = x + 1
    If x < 3 Then
        Debug.Print "Chrome Driver Test, try " & x
        On Error GoTo InstallOverride
    Else
        Call FixChromeDriver
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If
    Set driverTest = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    With driverTest
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Get "https://www.google.com"
        .Quit
    End With
    Set driverTest = Nothing
```

Comment: UAC is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  If you can't turn off UAC or change the user's privileges on that machine then you should stop right there.   It would be very dangerous to workaround this. (I think  the most you could do anyway is elevate privileges and that would not get around a UAC prompt) On a side note it can also be very dangerous to run Selenium in this sort of environment.  Make sure the driver only navigates to web sites under the company's control as you've effectively poked a hole through the normal browser sandbox.

Comment: for a reasonable alternative, you might consider building a dedicated machine which can run the tasks for you.  You could, for instance, run an intranet for this with domain based logins.  Then a dedicated back-end, or even a remote-grid that runs the automations in controlled/isolated machines.

Comment: I do understand the point of the UAC however this is a known driver that is fine, as its been installed on plenty of other machines and any user has the ability to select "run anyway" when this prompt comes up. To the second point, atleast in the manor that I have made these macros they physically open the browsers and navigate, meaning that restricted sites from the network cannot get through